# Airflow dependencies with Task decorator

Tags: python, airflow

I have an Airflow DAG that I can't figure out how to implement one particular dependency.

The code looks like this:

```
# Setup DAG
@dag(
    dag_id="dag_1",
    description="Dag 1 desc",
    schedule=DAG_SCHEDULE,
    start_date=days_ago(0),
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        "retries": 0,
    },
)
def dag_runner():
    @task(task_id="task_1")
    def task_1():
        //some logic
        return task_1_val

    @task(task_id="task_2")
    def task_2(input1):
        //some logic using input1
        return task_2_val

    @task(task_id="task_1")
    def task_3():
        //some logic
        //no return value

    @task(task_id="task_4")
    def task_4():
        //some logic
        return task_4_val

    @task(task_id="task_5")
    def task_5(input1, input2):
        //some logic using input1 & input2
        return task_5_val

    task_1_val = task_1()
    task_2_val = task_2(task_1_val)
    task_3()
    task_4_val = task_4()
    task_5_val = task_5(task_2_val, task_4_val)
```

Currently, `task_1`, `task_3` and `task_4` all run in parallel when the DAG starts.

`task_2` will start when `task_1` completes due to it requiring the return value of `task_1`.

I am happy with `task_3` running at the same time as `task_1`, but I want `task_4` to run once `task_3` has completed (even though it doesn't depend on a return value).

I know I could return a value from `task_3` and pass it to `task_4` but that seems hacky when I won't use the value.

I've tried adding this below the above code, but it doesn't apply any dependencies:

```
task_3 >> task_4
```

When I tried moving it above the `task_1_val = task_1()` line, I got the following error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for >>: '_TaskDecorator' and '_TaskDecorator'
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using taskflow API then you will have to call a task function like `task1()` just referencing like `task1` does not work. below code should achieve what you want.

```
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

from airflow.decorators import dag, task


# Setup DAG
@dag(
    dag_id="dag_1",
    description="Dag 1 desc",
    schedule="@daily",
    start_date=days_ago(0),
    catchup=False,
)
def dag_runner():
    @task
    def task_1():
        # some logic
        return "task_1_val"

    @task
    def task_2(input1):
        # some logic using input1
        return "task_2_val"

    @task
    def task_3():
        # some logic
        # no return value
        pass

    @task
    def task_4():
        # //some logic
        return "task_4_val"

    @task
    def task_5(input1, input2):
        # some logic using input1 & input2
        return "task_5_val"

    task2_val = task_2(task_1())
    task4_val = task_4()
    task_3() >> task4_val
    task_5(task2_val, task4_val)


dag_runner()
```